# Making Datagrid Searchable with MySQL database in C# WPF

Tags: c#, mysql

So i got my dataGrid working in C# WPF, it connects to my MySQL database and shows the first name and last name of people in the database. What I'm trying to do now is make a search button that searches for the last name entered in a text box and display only those in the datagrid. I know this code will be wrong but I just don't know how to do this. Thanks for the help

This connects to the database to get first name last name and it WORKS fine

```
try
{
    command = connc.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM studentinfo";
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result += reader["First_name"].ToString() + " " + 
        reader["Last_name"].ToString() + " ";
    }
    read = result.Split(' ');
    reader.Close();
    int count = 0;


    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM 
    studentinfo", connc);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    data.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = 
    DS.Tables[0] });

    MessageBox.Show("S");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("something went wrong: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Here im trying to use a textbox to make the datagrid searchable

```
    command = connc.CreateCommand();
    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Last_name FROM studentinfo 
    WHERE Last_name = @Last_name", connc);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_name", txtsearch.Text);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    data.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = 
    DS.Tables[0] });

    MessageBox.Show("S");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("something went wrong: " + ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    connc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the piece of code where you are using your textbox, you are never doing the while(reader.read()){}-loop.

Then, to make your life easier: create a class "Student"
You are putting everything in strings, gluing them together with a space, and then seperating them with the "split"-method. That's like torturing yourself.
Do something like:

```
 public class Student
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;

        public Student(string pFirstName, string pLastName)
        {
            firstname = pFirstName;
            lastname = pLastName;
        }

        public string Firstname
        {
            get { return firstname; }
            set { firstname = value; }
        }

        public string Lastname
        {
            get { return lastname; }
            set { lastname = value; }
        }

    }
```

Then you can use a list of Students to fill it up while doing your Reader.read()-thing:

```
List<Student> results = new List<Student>();
// build your connection
while(reader.read())
{
results.add(new Student(reader["First_name"], reader["Last_name"]));
}
```

Then you can place a BindingSource on your form and say:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = results;
publisherDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```